# Java Program does not give the output for values of n>6, Why?

Tags: java, freeze

```
import java.util.*;
class A{
   static int count=0;
   static String s;

   public static void main(String z[]){
      int n;
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      n=sc.nextInt();
      System.out.println(noOfBouncy(n));
   }

   public static int noOfBouncy(int k){
      int limit=(int)Math.pow(10,k);

       s=new String("1");
       int num=Integer.parseInt(s);
       while(num<limit){
          if(isIncreasing(s) || isDecreasing(s) ){
          }
          else{
            count++;
          }
          num++;
          s=new String(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(s)+1));
       }
       count=limit-count;
       return count; 
   }
}
public static boolean isIncreasing(String s){
     int len=s.length();
     for(int i=0;i<len-1;i++){
         if(s.charAt(i)>s.charAt(i+1)){
             return false;
         }
    }
return true;    
}
public static boolean isDecreasing(String s){
     int len=s.length();
     for(int i=0;i<len-1;i++){
         if(s.charAt(i)<s.charAt(i+1)){
             return false;
         }
    }
return true;
}
```

I have given the definitions to the two functions used isIncreasing() & isDecresing()

The program runs well for the value of n<7 but does not respond for values above it, Why ?

I accept the programming style is very immature,please ignore.

Comment: Why are you constantly converting between `String` and `int`?

Comment: Please give definitions of `isIncreasing` and `isDecreasing`.

Comment: Every time you increase `n` by 1, this should take 10 times as long to run. Are you sure that it is actually getting stuck, as opposed to simply taking longer than you are prepared to wait?

Comment: Could you explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: @JonK Since "String" is immutable and I need to update it every time the loop completes its execution once.

Comment: @SubOptimal I am trying to find number of nonBouncy numbers below 10^10

Comment: @JonK Since the main task is to check for the bouncy numbers and for that i need to parse the number character by character so that i can compare each character(number) to the one next to it.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes it took much time but I got the result !

Comment: Your logic is wrong for example for: 777. It's a bouncy number, but your code count it as increasing.

Comment: @SubOptimal No it is not, please have a look if wrong please give a hint to correct it.

Comment: @SubOptimal Actually according to the problem statement 134468 is counted as increasing only.

Comment: @Milind The condition in `isIncreasing` `s.charAt(i)>s.charAt(i+1)` is never true, as all digits are the same. So at the end the method return with `true`. But it should return in that case with `false`, as it's not a increasing number.

Comment: @SubOptimal I rechecked the problem statement and it counts 134468 as increasing and 66420 as decreasing, in that case if the next number is same as the previous the condition should remain true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried to execute it with n=7 and it finishes in 810ms, returning 30817.

However, I recommend to you to optimize the performance of your program by saving unnecessary object instantiation: It will be better if you maintain the counter in `num`, and convert it to string *just once*, at the beginning of the loop:

```
    int num=1;
    while (num < limit)
    {
        s=Integer.toString(num);
        if (isIncreasing(s) || isDecreasing(s))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            count++;
        }
        num++;
    }
```

Like this it takes just 450ms to finish.

Comment: But shouldn't it be 987048 bouncy numbers below one million?

Comment: Yes i need to count non bouncy numbers that's why I return (limit-count) from the function, although as per naming convention i should correct my functions name :)

Comment: @Milind Ok. I was confused by this inverted logic. It would be better, when your code would reflect this (by count the sum of increasing / decreasing numbers).

Comment: @SubOptimal Any hint on how can I optimize this code for faster execution ?

Comment: @Milind Avoid the convertion to `String`. Do it on a mathematical way.

Comment: @SubOptimal I feel the isIncreasing( ) & isDecreasing are working perfectly fine. What i feel is that, the problem is there in noOfBouncy() isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

The program was not actually stuck but it is taking way too much time to complete its execution when value of 'n' is larger.

So now the question is, I need to optimize the code to take minimum time @Little have an optimization bit that's not enough.

Any hint would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

To increase the performance you should avoid the conversation to `String` and do the check with numbers.

As it doesn't matter for the result if you start the comparison from left to right or from right to left one computational solution could be.

as pseudo code

```
1) compare the value of the right most digit with the digit on it's left
2) is it lower --> we found a decreasing pair
3) else check if it is bigger --> we found an increasing pair
4) else --> not a bouncy pair
5) if we found already one decreasing and one increasing pair it's bouncy number
6) divide the number by ten if it's bigger then ten repeat with step 1)
```

The method to check if it's a bouncy number could look like this

```
static boolean isBouncyNumber(int number) {

    boolean increasingNumber = false;
    boolean decreasingNumber = false;

    int previousUnitPosition = number % 10;
    int remainder = number / 10;

    while (remainder > 0) {
        // step 1
        int currentUnitPosition = remainder % 10;
        if (currentUnitPosition > previousUnitPosition) {
            // step 2
            decreasingNumber = true;
        } else if (currentUnitPosition < previousUnitPosition) {
            // step 3
            increasingNumber = true;
        }

        // step 5
        if (decreasingNumber && increasingNumber) {
            return true;
        }
        // step 6
        previousUnitPosition = currentUnitPosition;
        remainder = remainder / 10;
    }

    return decreasingNumber && increasingNumber;
}
```